# How to go to next JPanel depending on combo box selection?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jcombobox

I am creating a combo box with options "Checking","Savings","Credit Card".
When the user selects "Checking" option, it should directly go to "CheckingJPanel".

I am using card layout.

Comment: Please show us the code you have written.  If you haven't written any yet: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CardLayout`. It allows you to swap panels in the same place on the frame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use a CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a working example that does exactly what you want.